# Music Box issues

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, debugging, audio

Trying to push audio files into array. I don't understand why its not working. I've assigned the file to the array and used the push method. When I print out what is in the array it still reads null but has the correct length for the array whats going wrong?

```
var curr_audio = [];
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < notesParsed.length; i++)
    {
        if(notesParsed[i] == 'A')
            {
                curr_audio.push(new Audio("audio.Mp3/GameTone1.mp3"));
            }
        if(notesParsed[i] == 'B')
            {
                curr_audio.push(new Audio("audio.Mp3/cartoonRiochet.mp3"));
            }
        if(notesParsed[i] == 'C')
            {
                curr_audio.push(new Audio("audio.Mp3/cymbal_crash.mp3"));
            }
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(curr_audio));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) docs. You can see that data structures, eg sets are not properly serializable.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([new Set([1])]))
```

It is the same thing with Audio.

If you console.log the result instead you should see that they are actually there.

```js
const audioArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  audioArray.push(new Audio())
}
console.log('With stringify', JSON.stringify(audioArray))
console.log('Without stringify', audioArray)
```